# How can I extract Private keys / certifications from Nox Emulator running Android Pie? (9.0)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-keystore

I am running a Nox instance with Android 9.0 64 bit. I have an app I want to extract 2 specific keystore entries from (A certificate and a Private key). I always ran the app on Android 7, and used a python script to decrypt the keys using a masterkey and my screen lock PIN.

While I can still see the correct files in the /data/misc/keystore/user_0/ directory on the Emulator, the decryption script no longer works (Error relating to padding).

I have been trying for days now, with Objection, Frida and any other tool I can think off. However, I am not getting any closer. I did find out that the app uses the android.keystore.getKey(string,null) function to get a key, but that is about as far as I came.

Since this is an emulator, there should be no hardware backed storage. Is there any way to get the files from the keystore directory in a usable format?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!